# Не пойму что означает часть после `personid=statement`

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

```sql
SELECT lookup.illustrationid, lookup.personid,person.birthday
FROM lookup
LEFT JOIN person ON lookup.personid=person.personid=statement
TO JOIN birthday IN person table with primary illustration id;
```

Не пойму что означает часть после `personid=statement`?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это похоже на описание задания. :-)

Comment: Откуда запрос, будто что-то пропущено? Скорее всего опечатка из какой-либо книги...

Answer (score 1):

это кусок инструкции. читать как:

#### Join tables on common columns.

Выполните код

```
select lookup.illustrationid, lookup.personid,person.birthday from lookup 
left join person on lookup.personid=person.personid
```

чтобы соединить дни рождения (birthday) в таблице person с основной таблицей <картинка>

дальше по тексту идет Switch to the mysql db. Create a new user.

Скопипащено из [безвестного kb](http://www.letshostbilling.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=209). В таком кривом виде оно ушло в печать в книге `Mysql Interview Question And Answer` от [Damyanti Pathak](https://books.google.by/books?id=UTe-BAAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PA99&lpg=RA1-PA99&dq=%22SELECT+lookup.illustrationid,+lookup.personid,person.birthday%22&source=bl&ots=vTCMtJK70o&sig=qOAcHjomJJCBeQJescTjN-zaDao&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H_paVdrqPMqjsAG2hICYBw&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false). Опасайтесь подделок!